# Is there a way to bookmark / follow questions or answers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, questions

Most times, it happens that you come across certain questions / answers / suggestions, that you would want to save / bookmark for future. Is there a way to do that on Stack Overflow?

If not, may be this should be a feature that Stack Overflow should have.

Can we favorite an answer or a comment? I am asking because, some questions do have long and multiple answers, so instead of scrolling / searching, can we favorite and directly view them later?

Comment: Thanks for marking it as duplicate but the duplicate question doesn't answer the question in context.

Comment: The duplicate asks for the same feature you're asking for. That such a feature does not exist does not make these questions different to each other.

Comment: @Milan Doesn't have your browser a bookmark feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just *favorite* them, then they'll appear under the 'favorites' tab in your profile.

EDIT:

This functionality is restricted to questions only, so individual answers/comments cannot be favorited/bookmarked.

Comment: Thanks @CinCout
Can we favorite an answer or a comment? I am asking because, some questions do have long and multiple answers, so instead of scrolling / searching, can we favorite and directly view them later?

Comment: [Here's an illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrerK.png).